# Set workflow variables from another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that is up and running, and uses email addresses for variables. Everything works fine but I was wondering if I could link the variables to a new list that contains the email addresses? The idea being that it will allow others to update the list of users in each department when required.

Thanks in advance
Dave
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can Set the variables from another list but you should be able to link both lists somehow in order to identify the specific email address on the new list.

[image]