# How to use Call HTTP web service action in SP Workflow to get an item from another list?

Tags: designer-workflow, web-services, sharepoint-rest-api

I would like to pass an ID as a filter via REST api using call http webservice action in SP Workflow.

The workflow should trigger the action (the web service) and return a field value from another list on same web(site).

Is this achievable? Any other solution to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes , this is possible in workflow. do you have a lookup in your second list from first list?

Comment: No lookup.I just  want to pass an id to filter to retrieve a single value

Comment: If you want to retrieve only single item then you don't need to use REST call. I think there is another action to get the single field from another list.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Any resources online you can point me to?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the single field from another list by passing filter value then you don't need to use the "Call HTTP web servie" action.

You can get the value of field using "Set workflow variable" action.
Follow the Steps given below:

1. Add "Set workflow varibale" action in your workflow.
2. Click on **value** and then `fx`.
3. Select **Data Source** to your another list.
4. Select the field you want to retrieve from **Field from source** dropdown.
5. When you select the data source to another list, it automatically adds on more block on the set workflow variable popup as **Find the List Item**.
6. In this block, you can add you filter to retrieve the specific item from another list.
7. Select the **Field** from dropdown on which you want to add the filter.
8. Pass the the filter value in **value** section, either a hard coded string or you can pass varibales as well using `fx`.

[Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239975/set-workflow-variables-from-another-list) is an example of how to set the workflow variable from another list.

Comment: have you tried this?